# LINQ Group elements that are equal together

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple question on LINQ and haven't found an answer that directly addresses my question. Say I have an arbitrary collection of objects: `{cat, apple, orange, cat, orange, apple, cat}`. I want to order to use LINQ to order these lists by equality, e.g. so now the collection reads `{apple, apple, orange, orange, cat, cat, cat}`. It doesn't matter what order the types are (i.e. whether apple comes first or cat, for example), only that they are appropriately grouped.

Say I have access to Equals() or some boolean method to determine if any two instances are equal. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort the list. Since equal elements have the same rank in the order, they will be grouped together:

```
 var items = new []{"cat", "apple", "orange", "cat", "orange", "apple", "cat"};
 var sorted = items.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Result:

> apple apple cat cat cat orange orange

Answer (score 2):

Sorting has complexity `O(n log n)`. The following, has linear complexity.

```
collection.GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

Comment: With the number of elements I am processing, time complexity isn't crucially important, however that is still useful to know when sorting larger collections, thanks.

Comment: sure buy why not accept the solution that has linear complexity ?

Comment: This method is 50x faster than `OrderBy` for large collections (100_000 elements or more).

Answer (score 1):

As you can access the Equals() and it works, the GetHashCode() have to be rewritten and could work now. So, you can order by object.GetHashCode(), it will give you the result.

The code will just like @zhulien's answer.

```
collection.OrderBy(o => o.GetHashCode());
```

Comment: The version with ```GetHashCode``` can fail. Please consider what happens if two different elements have same hash code but different values (rare but not impossible).

Comment: @SamuelVidal I think you're right, this method is not strict.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = new List<string> { "cat", "apple", "orange", "cat", "orange", "apple", "cat" };
var orderedAlphabetically = values.OrderBy(v => v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Adrian said,

If you wanted to group them together...

```
var items = new []{"cat", "apple", "orange", "cat", "orange", "apple", "cat"};
var sorted = items.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x);
```

You now have 3 distinct groups ordered by their count

> apple orange cat

You can further iterate over the group

```
foreach (var x in sorted)
{
   foreach (var y in x)
   {
      Console.Write(y);
    }
}
```

> apple apple orange orange cat cat cat

Answer (score -2):

A quick solution would be to order by object hash code. The code should look something like:

```
collection.OrderBy(o => o.GetHashCode());
```

Another option is to use `GroupBy` to group the objects by Equality, HashCode or some custom Comparer function and then flatten the collection again.

```
collection.GroupBy(o => o.GetHashCode()).SelectMany(o => o);
```

or

```
collection.GroupBy(o => o, <CustomComparerFunction>).SelectMany(o => o);
```

Comment: The version with ```GetHashCode``` can fail if two different elements have same hash code but different value (rare but can happen).

Comment: @SamuelVidal The author should override GetHashCode and Equals to fit his needs. Also, your comment is totally invalid as this solution will work with actual objects(like the author stated) and not just simple types as in the case of your solution. Your solution is flawed in the sense that GroupBy, without a Comparer function provided, uses the Default Object Comparer which is based on GetHashCode and Equals methods. Furthermore, the default Equals method compares reference types by object reference, which will obviously provide wrong results in your case.

Comment: I see you point, but still I maintain that using GetHashCode alone, is incorrect: consider the degenerate but valid case where GetHashCode returns zero uniformly, this will not produce the required grouping. The semantic of the Equals method is perfectly correct, I beg to disagree.

Comment: @zhulien overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` is inflexible. It is OK for a custom `ValueType`, but for objects more complex than that it is preferable to provide custom implementations of [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1). This way you gain the flexibility of comparing your objects in multiple ways (by Name, by Age, by Price etc).